# Subadditivity of Kodaira dimension

Tags: complex-geometry, kodaira-dimension, ag.algebraic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Given an algebraic fiber space $X \to B$ where $X$ and $B$ are smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, it is known that the Kodaira dimensions satisfy the following subadditivity property:
$$\kappa(X) \ge \kappa(\text{general fiber}) + \kappa(B).$$
Does the same property holds for compact Kähler manifolds? If it is still unknown, are there any partial results in this direction?

Comment: That statement is not known in general for projective varieties: that is the Iitaka conjecture.

Comment: By the way, if you're interested in knowing how much is known about the Iitaka conjecture in the projective setting, one reference is the following paper by Birkar: dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~cb496/iitaka-6.pdf. There, he shows that it is true when dim X (in your notation) is 6 or less, and also if dim B is 2 and the general fibre F has Kodaira dimension 0.

Comment: If $X$ is just a compact complex manifold (not Kähler), then the statement is false. There is an example in the book of K. Ueno, "Classification theory of algebraic varieties and compact complex spaces", see the reference on page 1 of this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.3165. I am not aware of any Kähler counterexample.

Comment: see http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Gazette/2010/125/smf_gazette_125_119-123.pdf

Comment: The subadditivity of the Kodaira dimension is known to be true for surjective morphisms $f$ from a threefold $V$ to a curve or a surface $X$, i.e.: $$\kappa(V)≥\kappa(X)+\kappa(V_x)$$, where $V_x$ is the general fibre of $f$, provided that $V$ is algebraic. Atiyah and Blanchard showed that the algebraicity is really necessary, by giving examples of analytic threefolds, not bimeromorphic to a Kähler manifold, and morphisms $f$, whose general fibre $V_x$ is bimeromorphic to a torus or a $K3$ surface, such that the corresponding inequality fails.

Comment: Let $f:X→Y$ be a surjective morphism between nonsingular projective varieties defined over $\mathbb C$ and suppose that any general fiber of $f$ is connected.  Set $$F_m=f_∗ω_{X/Y}^{\otimes m}$$ for each positive integer $m$. To prove subaddivity it is just need we show that  $F_m$ is a semipositive locally free sheaf on $Y$ if $Y$ is a curve.